# Python regex: change one symbol into two

Tags: python, regex

Suppose you link a symbol as follows:

```
iff = chr(8801)
```

And then you write that code over all your algorithm in several spaces.  Now suppose you decided that the following symbol has almost all of the same properties as the previous:

```
jiff = chr(10231)
```

Rather than go back and change every instance of:

```
if b == iff:
```

to

```
if b in [iff, jiff]:
```

I instead was wondering if there were some regex where I could make it so that the former code

```
if b == iff:
```

will register true if b is either = to iff or jiff. I was thinking of some regex but you would still have to change every instance of:

```
if b == iff:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just change all instances; from a design standpoint this will probably make your life easier in the long run, and won't confuse people who read the code, unlike the alternatives. But to avoid making the same mistake again, you can have a list of acceptable symbols:

```
accept = [iff, jiff]

...

if b in accept:
    ...
```

Now you just need to modify your symbols in one place.

If you *really* want to avoid changing all instances of that `if`-statement, you can make `iff` be a special object that overrides `__eq__` to return true if the symbol is either `iff` or `jiff`:

```
class Sym:
    def __eq__(self, s):
        return s in (chr(8801), chr(10231))

iff = Sym()
```

(But this will break if `iff` is used elsewhere if an actual string is expected.)

Comment: actually, the symbol appeared far less than I thought it did.  So I've already changed it.

Comment: @robertford Okay, I think that's the right choice anyway. Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it helped you.